# Batch file to copy files to many machines

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I need to have a batch file that copies files (8) in my local directory to either a list of machines on the network (hostname or IP) or have me prompt to enter the next hostname/ip

I'd prefer not to have to run the script over and over again to enter the next hostname/ip

I'll also need to see the output for each system to make sure it connected correctly and copied successfully. Perhaps a "ready to process next?" after each machine?

I don't know how to have a batch file does the equivalent of `STDIN`, so please forgive the `?STDIN?` placeholder

So far, all I have is

```
net use S: \\?STDIN?\C$ /user:domain\myusername mypassword  

copy %~file01.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file02.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file03.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file04.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file05.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file06.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file07.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y
copy %~file08.txt S:\%SystemRoot%\system32 /y

net use :s /delete

do it again
```

Comment: I ended up using "windows" instead of systemroot and also removed %~ (which allowed it to run under system context and not from the command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prompt the user for input (and store it into an environment variable) with the `set /p` command:

```
set /p HOST=Machine?
net use S: \\%HOST%\C$ ...
```

You can loop by using a label and jump to it. You should offer a way to exit, though:

```
:loop
set /p HOST=Machine? (leave blank to exit)
if [%HOST%]==[] goto :EOF
net use S: \\%HOST%\C$ ...
copy ...
...
goto loop
```

If you don't want to enter each host name individually you can also loop over the arguments to the batch file:

```
:loop
if [%1]==[] goto :EOF
net use S: \\%1\C$ ...
copy ...
...
shift
goto loop
```

You can can call it as follows, then:

```
my_batch machine1 machine2 192.168.12.14 ...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "if ERRORLEVEL 1" to see if an error occurred in the copy which will allow you to trap for problems with the copy.  Along with a "if EXIST" to check that the file is there, though, you may get some files that are zero length.

Though, you may want to investigate Powershell as a more capable tool for the job.